# I can't find any error that will lead to this result

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, uppercase, lowercase

I am new to C++ and want to test out how much I actually learned so I made this simple cRaZyTeXt generator. But there's a weird bug I can't find any way to solve.

Codes are here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>

char convertToUppercase (char x)
{
    int asciiCode {static_cast<int>(x) - 32};
    char y {static_cast<char>(asciiCode)};

    return y;
}

char convertToLowercase (char x)
{
    int asciiCode {static_cast<int>(x) + 32};
    char y {static_cast<char>(asciiCode)};

    return y;
}

void toClipboard(const std::string &s){
    OpenClipboard(0);
    EmptyClipboard();
    HGLOBAL hg=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,s.size() + 1);
    if (!hg){
        CloseClipboard();
        return;
    }
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hg),s.c_str(),s.size() + 1);
    GlobalUnlock(hg);
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,hg);
    CloseClipboard();
    GlobalFree(hg);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the text you want to convert into cRaZy TeXt: " << '\n';
    std::string userInput {};
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, userInput);

    char userInputArray [userInput.size()];
    std::copy(userInput.begin(), userInput.end(), userInputArray);

    char outputArray [userInput.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.size(); ++i)
    {
        int x {static_cast<int>(userInputArray[i])};
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (x <= 90 && x >= 65)
                outputArray[i] = convertToLowercase(userInputArray[i]);
            else
                outputArray[i] = userInputArray[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if (x <= 122 && x >= 97)
                outputArray[i] = convertToUppercase(userInputArray[i]);

            else
                outputArray[i] = userInputArray[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << outputArray << '\n';
    toClipboard(outputArray);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

when I enter `Hello, world!`, it can output `hElLo, WoRlD!` as exactly how I want it to be. [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNSCD.png)

But when I try `my name is sean.`, its output would look like this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4l7f.png)

```
mY NaMe iS SeAn.@y name is sean.@%�
```

What's more weird is that both `my name is ma sean.` and `my name is sean ma.` works fine.

[my name is ma sean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMeiU.png)

[my name is sean ma.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbMlT.png)

I have tried above four inputs in both release and debug configuration and it's all the same.

Please elaborate on the issue and make the explanation friendlier for beginners.

Any helps are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not seeing this issue if I strip out the clipboard stuff and run under Linux.

Comment: As someone else pointed out though, you aren't null terminating `outputArray` so that could be your issue. Try `char outputArray [userInput.size()] = {0};` which ensures your c string is always null terminated.

Comment: Also... can you even do that? You can't dynamically create arrays like that. Use `std::string` or else you have to use `new` to create a dynamically sized array.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.size(); ++i)` is off by one. it will cause undefined behavior by trying to read and write out of bounds.

Comment: Also `char outputArray [userInput.size()];` is non-standard C++. Better use a `std::string` with it's `push_back` method.

Comment: Minus the windows-specific clipboard infusion, it seems all you're really trying to do [is this](https://godbolt.org/z/K4PMWznGa).

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel. `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` do case conversions more efficiently and more portably then the code here.

Comment: @WhozCraig — there’s no need for that `std::isalpha` test. `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` work for all valid characters.

Comment: @PeteBecker I didn't put it there on accident. It prevents incrementing `i` on non-alphabetic chars, thereby ensuring a case flip only on said-same (alpha chars).

Comment: @WhozCraig — okay, I see now why you’re doing that. But I don’t think that’s a requirement. Look at the two linked examples.

Comment: @Gillespie for your second comment: when I add `= {0}`, it shows an error that says `variable-sized object cannot be initialized`.

Comment: @WhozCraig for your first comment: I can see your solution's far better than mine. But I have never heard of `cctype` before, so for me I can only come up with this solution by now.

Comment: cctype is the C++ standard library name of the ctype.h header you’re probably more familiar with.

Comment: so obviously I haven't learn enough to do this. Will look into that header afterwards. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @churill for the first comment: thank you for pointing this out. It should be `for (int i = 0; i < userInput.size(); ++i)` is it?

and for the second comment: can you elaborate on or give an example of how to use `std::string` and its `push_back` method? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters variable length arrays as for example the declaration of this array

```
char userInputArray [userInput.size()];
```

is not a standard C++ feature.

There is no need to use auxiliary arrays to perform the task. You could change the original object `userInput` of the type `std::string` itself.

This variable length array

```
char outputArray [userInput.size()];
```

does not contain a space for the terminating zero character `'\0'` to make the stored sequence of characters a string.

As a result this output

```
std::cout << outputArray << '\n';
```

invokes undefined behavior.

This for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.size(); ++i)
```

leads to access memory beyond the declared variable length arrays because the valid range of indices is `[ 0, userInput.size() )`.

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like for example 65 or 90. This makes the code unreadable.

If I have understood correctly what you need is a function like the following shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string & cRaZyTeXt_generator( std::string &s )
{
    int upper_case = 1;

    for (auto &c : s)
    {
        if ( std::isalpha( static_cast< unsigned char >( c ) ) )
        {
            if ( ( upper_case ^= 1 ) )
            {
                c = std::toupper( static_cast< unsigned char >( c ) );
            }
            else
            {
                c = std::tolower( static_cast< unsigned char >( c ) );
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( "Hello, World!" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << cRaZyTeXt_generator( s ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello, World!
hElLo, WoRlD!
```

Comment: > This variable length array char outputArray [userInput.size()]; does not contain a space for the terminating zero character '\0' to make the stored sequence of characters a string. 


Can you elaborate on this? I read up some tutorials, and they say that C++ arrays comes with '\0' thing in the end. So should I make it char outputArray [userInput.size() + 1];? Also for the magic number thing, I figured out I should probably at least add a comment next to it or use static_cast<int>('a') to get its ASCII code

Comment: @Seanmamasde You are filling the array yourself. So you need use at least outputArray [userInput.size() + 1]; and explicitly append the stored sequence of characters with the terminating zero character.